# Induced topology of varieties

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I am looking at Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, chapter I.3 Morphisms.

The function $f:Y\to k$ is regular at $p\in Y$ if there is an open set $p\in U\subseteq Y$ which $g,h\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ which $h\neq 0$ in $U$ and $f=g/h$ at every point of $U$.

So I have to know the induced topology of $Y$, but I don't know the topology for $Y$ if it is not affine or projective $n$-space. Should I just use the subspace topology, or did I miss something from the book?

Comment: Yes, the topology on a quasi-affine or quasi-projective variety is induced from the Zariski topology on affine or projective space respectively. Also, I think that $h\not\equiv 0$ in $U$ means that $h$ does not vanish identically on $U$, which is not the same to having no zeros on $U$.

Comment: @danneks Thank you for the comment. So would it be okay to think of the topology of any variety as a subspace topology of the corresponding affine or projective space? Also I edited the question.

Comment: If a variety comes with an embedding to an affine or projective space, then it is OK. Or one can define the Zariski topology locally by gluing.